# Fastest Way to Check if Image is Onscreen Using pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have the following code:

```
b_counter = False

while (b_counter == False):
    if (pyautogui.locateOnScreen('editcheck.png') is not None):
            pyautogui.click(pyautogui.center(pyautogui.locateOnScreen('home.png')))
            b_counter = True
```

The loop lags when running, sometimes up to 10 seconds after the image has loaded.  My machine itself is pretty fast (i7 16gb ram etc).  Is there any way to speed up this loop?

I'm loading webpages so the "home" buttons do not appear immediately.  This loop occurs after pyautogui has entered in the web address to load.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found an answer to my question.  Select a region to make the search feature faster.  This way, the program won't be searching through the whole screen, just a specific region.

ex:

```
    import pyauotgui
    pyautogui.locateOnScreen('test.png', region = (0,0,400,400))
```

where region = left, top, width, height

Comment: is there any faster way to do that?

Comment: I'm writing a code to play a game for me, and it is time limited, so I want to tune my program to make it faster, it needs to find an image among other images and select it, and then the images shuffle

Answer (score 2):

simple way

```
if (pyautogui.locateOnScreen('test.PNG') is not None):
    pyautogui.hotkey('win', 'l')
```